# DRF: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pk'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, attributeerror

I am using Django Rest Framework. I have a model TestSuite which has Foreign key relations to the model Team and EmailTemplates. When I do a post() to Test Suite through postman, the data is inserted in the TestSuite table and request works successfully. However, when I do a get() or try to click on the url link from localhost to access TestSuite, it throws below error

```
 AttributeError at /dqf_api/test_suite/
 'str' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

error traceback

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py" in inner
52.                 return func(*args, **kwds)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
116.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
495.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
455.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
492.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in list
48.         return Response(serializer.data)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
768.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
262.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
686.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in <listcomp>
686.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
530.                 ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/relations.py" in to_representation
272.         return value.pk

Exception Type: AttributeError at /dqf_api/test_suites/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

models.py

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'team'

class TestSuite(models.Model):
    team_name = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='team_name')
    suite_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    schedule = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    email_list_ok = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
email_list_fail = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
template_name = models.ForeignKey(EmailTemplates, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='template_name')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'test_suite'
        unique_together = (('team_name', 'suite_name'),)
```

views.py

```
class TestSuiteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.TestSuite.objects.values('team_name','suite_name', 'description','schedule','email_list_ok','email_list_fail','template_name')
    serializer_class = serializers.TestSuiteSerializer

class TeamViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Team.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TeamSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
class TestSuiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.TestSuite
        fields = ['team_name','suite_name', 'description','schedule','email_list_ok','email_list_fail','template_name']
```

Can someone please help here. I am new to django and DRF

**EDIT**
When I used queryset = models.TestSuite.objects.all() in serializers.py, it throws below error.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
71.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
206.         res = self._query(query)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _query
312.         db.query(q)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in query
224.         _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

The above exception ((1054, "Unknown column 'test_suite.id' in 'field list'")) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py" in inner
52.                 return func(*args, **kwds)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
116.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
495.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
455.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
492.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in list
48.         return Response(serializer.data)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
768.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
262.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
686.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
272.         self._fetch_all()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
1179.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
54.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
1064.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
71.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
206.         res = self._query(query)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _query
312.         db.query(q)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in query
224.         _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /dqf_api/test_suites/
Exception Value: (1054, "Unknown column 'test_suite.id' in 'field list'")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
class TestSuiteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.TestSuite.objects.values('team_name','suite_name', 'description','schedule','email_list_ok','email_list_fail','template_name')  # <-- Here
    serializer_class = serializers.TestSuiteSerializer
```

You need to provide a [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/), not a [dictionary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values). So it should be like this:

```
class TestSuiteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.TestSuite.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TestSuiteSerializer
```

Comment: I am not using queryset because I have a composite primary key(team_name,suite_name) in TestSuite model and django doesn't allow defining multiple pk. So I thought of using django's auto generate 'id' as pk. I cannot store 'id' in my database as I am using existing db to which I cannot make any changes.
I made the above changes and it throws below error:
OperationalError at /dqf_api/test_suites/
(1054, "Unknown column 'test_suite.id' in 'field list'")

Comment: Okay, I missed that part `managed=False`. Can you please explain more on `OperationalError at /dqf_api/test_suites/ (1054, "Unknown column 'test_suite.id' in 'field list'")`  in your question(with full stacktrace)?

Comment: Added the stack trace in above question. I think since I have not given any pk in the model, django creates 'id' field on its own, but when it tries to retrieve the 'id' with queryset, it fails as the 'id' column is not present in the DB

Comment: As you have added `managed=False`, django is not responsible for migrating your database. means you need to create that field yourself. Please add a new column in table named `id`, and see if it works.

Comment: I cannot modify the schema of the tables..I am not supposed to make any changes there..Without that is there any other way I can handle this? I do not need 'id' in my db

Comment: I don't think so. if you are planning to approach like this, then its better to avoid Generic Viewset, rather than that, you can create your custom viewset. Also I don't think Serializer would not work as well.